# Windows service connecting to other service over wcf crashes

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have two windows services. One ('server') acts as a WCF host to which the other ('client') connects. So I have configured a dependency from *client* to *server*. Both are also set up to start automatically.

When I start these services by hand, everything works fine. When I stop both services and tell *client* to start, then *server* will be started before *client* and all is fine.

However, when I reboot the machine only *server* is started.

When I add a diagnostic listener I see it got a `TimeoutException` with the helpful message:

> *The HTTP request to 'http://[server address]' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.*

At some other SO question there was [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919287/wcf-windows-service-timeout/942557#942557) that claims WCF is probably confused about what went wrong and therefore starts lying about the timeout.

Did I perhaps miss a dependency for either service? Does WCF require something that hasn't or is being started when *client* is trying to contact *server*?

Comment: Does your client depend on anything else?  Database perhaps?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't. The client is actually written by a colleague of mine but because I made the server, I'm the one assigned to fix it. Anyway what I suspected was that WCF somehow was the problem, which seems to be confirmed by the log.

Comment: The "...exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:00..." message can occur if DNS resolution of the server address uses up all of the configured/default WCF client send timeout. I imagine this might well happen when all services are restarting after a reboot. In general, it's best to assume WCF isn't lying in exception messages. I'm not aware of any messages which wrongly describe the nature of the error. (Though sometimes the additional suggestions included in the messages as to how to fix the problem may be wide of the mark - as in the linked answer).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check your client service. On startup windows services are starting while network devices are still being initialized. Services should be ready to start without network and without any network device. Usual approach is to keep periodic retries to establish connection. You can do little experiment on your machine by uninstalling all network adapters and trying to start up your services.

Additional quick workaround you can do is to setup recovery options on your service -- for example you can configure it to restart service on crash after some timeout -- you can do this through UI in services.msc or in command line using 'sc config' command.

Comment: Yes, that would be best. However, let's assume for a moment that isn't possible. Are you then able to select a dependency that will assure network dependencies are done initializing?

Comment: There is no "dependency" that would tell you that at least one network adapter finished initializing. If your service cannot start without network, you should not start it automatically on system startup. Configure it with manual start, then whenever you want to use it, first check if network is up, then start it up, then start using it.

Answer (score 2):

Configuring the dependency between the two Windows Services is not necessarily sufficient to avoid there being a race condition: i.e. to avoid the client service calling the WCF service before the server's WCF channel stack is fully initialised.

The service dependency just ensures that the Windows Service Control Manager won't start the client service process before the server Windows Service has notified the SCM that it has started. Whether this is sufficient depends on how you write the server.

If the server service starts a new thread on which to initialize the WCF stack, your `OnStart` method is probably returning before the WCF stack is ready for clients. There is then a race condition as to whether the client's first call will succeed.

On the other hand, if the server service does not return from OnStart (and thus doesn't notify the SCM that it has started) until the channel stack is fully open, the dependency removes the race condition, but there is a different pitfall: you need to beware that the SCM's own timeout for starting the Windows service is not triggered while waiting for the WCF stack to initialise, as might well happen on a reboot if the WCF service depends on the network stack, for example. If the server's `OnStart` does not return within the SCM's timeout, the SCM will not try to start the dependent client service at all, because it does not receive the server's start notification. (There will be a message in the Windows event log from the SCM saying that the server service didn't start within the expected time.) You can extend the SCM timeout by calling `ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime` while the WCF service is being initialised.

Either way, the client service really ought to be written so that it doesn't fail completely if the first WCF call doesn't succeed.

You don't actually say what binding you are using. If client and server services are always running on the same machine, as you seem to indicate, then consider using the NetNamedPipeBinding: then your service won't be dependent on initialization of networking resources and startup should be quicker.

Comment: What basically happens in OnStart is: initialize server; create serviceHost; serviceHost.Open; return. So as far as I know OnStart will take at least as long as needed create the host, but certainly not indefinitely. The NetNamedPipeBinding is a good suggestion.

Comment: @Patrick: The SCM only allows you 30 seconds to complete the OnStart event and have the base class send the start notification back to the SCM. I suspect you are exceeding this when rebooting, unless you explicitly ask for more time by calling `RequestAdditionalTime`.

Comment: As you can see in the question, an attempt is made to start the client (it even throws an exception). Therefor I conclude that the server is started quick enough.